# How do I manipulate an URL for webscraping with Python?

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I want to imput my array **tweets** which spits out a list of stock ticker symbols (aapl, cdti, ovas, etc.) individually into the URL https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=mbot In this URL the last portion of the URL, in this case, MBOT, is the stock that the page looks at. How do I manipulate the URL so I can scrape the information from each table with my array **tweets**?

```
    import csv
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
    twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

    print(soup.title.text)

    tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
    print(tweets)

    furl = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=mbot"
    fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(furl)
    fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

    with open('output.csv', 'wt') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
# write header row
writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

# write body row
writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you want. You get the ticker symbols you want from https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog. Based on this tweeter account you generate a list of ticker symbols.

So if you want to obtain the information for Apple (appl) then you would have https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl correct?

Why not have:

```
url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
url_list = [url_base + tckr for tckr in tweets]
```

Then you do a loop for the requests for each url in url_list. Is this close to what you were looking to achieving?